# how to make contents in my app universal?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have made an app that fits all my contents perfectly on Iphone 6, but when I run it on any other device, the positions are shifted. How do I fix this using UIKit on Xcode

Comment: How can you expect that we can be helpful on it? Please post some code and be more specific/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the size and position relevant to the screen size for example:

```
Image.position = CGPoint(x: (scene?.size.width)! * 0.1, y: (scene?.size.height)! * 0.2)

Image.size = CGSize(x: (scene?.size.width)! * 0.6, y: (scene?.size.height)! * 0.6)
```

i use scene as a reference majority of the time but frame size works as well by replacing the `(scene.size.height)!` portion with

```
(self.frame.size.width) or (self.frame.size.height)
```